# Template parse errors: 'md-grid-tile' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I use Material Design in new Angular 2. I connected this to app.module like as:

```
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MdGridListModule, MdCardModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
MdButtonModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdGridListModule,
    MdCardModule
  ],
```

When page is loaded I get errors in console:

```
VM1967 vendor.bundle.js:63286 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'md-grid-tile' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-grid-tile' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-grid-tile' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <md-grid-list cols="7" rowHeight="2" id="weekly_schedule">
```

How to fix? I tried any ways.

Full file is with connected material(now it dont give any errors but page is loaded unlimite in browser)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { QuoteService } from './quote.service';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MdGridListModule, MdCardModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    MdGridListModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    QuoteService
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: are you using any `shared-module`??

Comment: you can import a lot of module except the one that is required

Comment: How to check if I use `shared-module`?

Comment: I added all app.module file to question, it it works but can not load page. Seems it works in loop

Comment: Which version of @angular/materials are you using? Maybe a reinstall with the latest versin may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MaterialModule is removed as of 2.0.beta-11 as seen in the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes),
so you have to use **mat** instead of **md**. But still changes are going on so you need to track on git hub

Answer (score 2):

Replace **MGridListModule** to **MatGridListModule**,also do import as **import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material';**

you will be good to go..